# How to deploy specific LWC component in VS code?

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx-cli

1. I am using the command to push the code into the scratch org
2. sfdxforce:source:push
3. It deploys all components not specific. I am following the below
   link

   [ibit.ly/4MxW](https://ibit.ly/4MxW)

Comment: For example, if you have an HTML, JS, & CSS file in your component, you only want to push the CSS file? I don't think that's possible. Even the CLI as you've linked doesn't expose a means to deploy only one part of the component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can deploy a *specific* component (the JS, HTML, and CSS) with `project deploy start`:

```
sf project deploy start -d force-app/main/default/lwc/myComponent
```

Or:

```
sf force:source:deploy -m LightningComponentBundle:myComponent
```

Note that if you use `force sourch push`, it will deploy everything only the first time. Afterwards, only changed components would be deployed.

You may also simply right-click on the component (either its folder, or any individual file), and use the `SFDX: Deploy Source to Org` context menu item.